# Javascript "document.getElementById" can it replace test in the ID'ed element?

Tags: javascript

Just a very quick question. `document.getElementById`, can it **replace** the text already present in the referenced ID? I have tried fiddling with a few things, but it does not seem to be happening.

The code where I would like to use this is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<HEAD>

    <script>
        function runNumber(){
            num=(Math.round(Math.random()*9)+2);
            for (i = num; i > 0; i--) {
                for (j = num; j > 1; j--) {
                    document.getElementById("runBox").innerHTML += '1+';
                }
            document.getElementById("runBox").innerHTML += '1 <br>';
            }
        document.getElementById("runBox").innerHTML += 'The answer, of course, is <b>' + num + ' x ' + num + ' = ' + [num*num] + '</b>.<p></p>';
        }

        function sentNumber(num){
            for (i = num; i > 0; i--) {
                for (j = num; j > 1; j--) 
                    {document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML += '1+';}
            document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML += '1 <br>';
            }
        document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML += 'The answer is <b>' + num + ' x ' + num + ' = ' + [num*num] + '</b>.<p></p>';
        }
    </script>

</HEAD>

<BODY onload=runNumber()>
    <p><button onclick="history.go(0)">New Examples</button></p>
    <b>The Square Machine</b>
    <p id="runNumber"></p>
    The square of a number is a literal square.<p> So for calculating the square of <b>number x</b>, write down 1 as many times as the x in a grid (x number of rows and x number of columns, like below).<p> Then add all those numbers together, you will get the square of the number!<p> <b>Remember</b>: the square of any negative number is the same as the square of the positive version of that number.<p> Over time, you should know the squares of numbers 1-20 simply from memory.
    <center><p id="runBox"></p></center>

    Try your own number:
    <select id="sentNum">
         <script>
             for (var i = 2; i<=50; i++)
                {document.write("<option value="+i+"> "+i+" </option>");}
         </script>
    </select>

    <p>
    <p><button onclick="sentNumber(document.getElementById('sentNum').value)">Enter</button></p>
    <center>
        <p id="sentNumber"></p>
        <p id="sentBox"></p>
    </center>

    <p><center>
        <b>To do:</b> Nothing.</br>
        <a href="index.html">Home Page</a></center>
    </p>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Show the html as well.  You also aren't clearing the innerHTML before running, the j for loop seems pointless.  You should be able to handle that in an if statement.

Comment: I have just put the entire page's code into the original post above. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: The for j loop prints the rows for the square of the number, so it is a neat square. The idea is to show students that a square of a number is a literal square.

Comment: I read the question 5 times and I still a bit confused but my best guess is you went on every click to clear the sentBox before showing the new list of 1+1+1+1+1 etc.  If so just add document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML = ""; as the first line of the sentNumber function

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the `innerHTML` and the `id` is part of the `outerHTML` (the `innerHTML` is the `outerHTML` excluding the element's own code).

In any case it's not `getElementById` which is doing the modification, all it does is fetch the element.

Answer (score -1):

I think its working as expected.

```js
function sentNumber(num){
        for (i = num; i > 0; i--) {
            for (j = num; j > 1; j--) 
                {document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML = '1+';}
        document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML += '1 <br>';
        }
    document.getElementById("sentBox").innerHTML += 'The answer is <b>' + num + ' x ' + num + ' = ' + [num*num] + '</b>.<p></p>';
    }
sentNumber(10)
```

```html
<span id="sentBox"> </span>
```

<s>http://fiddle.jshell.net/5npfhecs/</s>